# Python -Pandas- How to return speicfic rows based on conditions and return the specific column rows only

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, filter

Have a dateframe and based on muliple conditions need to return the rows and to create a new column to store these rows.

Example

```
record = {
  'Name': ['Ankit', 'Amit', 'Aishwarya', 'Priyanka', 'Priya', 'Shaurya' ],
  'Age': [21, 19, 20, 18, 17, 21],
  'Stream': ['Math', 'Commerce', 'Science', 'Math', 'Math', 'Science'],
  'Percentage': [88, 92, 95, 70, 65, 78],hours=[1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Condition like : If age is in  19 & 21 , Stream in Maths, Commerce  then return hours along with the other records and these hours to be stored in a new column created for the rows returned

Example: Output:
New column added = `new_column`

```
Name      Age Stream Percentage hours new_column
Ankit     21  Math      88         1      1 
Amit      19 Commerce   92         2      2
Aishwarya 20 Science    95         3      0
Priyanka  18  Science   70         4      0
Priya     17  English   65         5      0
Shaurya   21  Science   78         6      0
```

The 0 value  in `new_column` since the filter conditions arent satisfied.
Tried below code , but the results not as expected and not a simplified version.

- Conditions:

```
options1 = ['Math', 'Commerce']
options2 = [21,19]
    
dataframe1=dataframe[(dataframe['Stream'].isin(options)) & (dataframe['Age'].isin(options2))]
dataframe1['new_column']=dataframe1['hours']
    
dataframe=pd.merge(dataframe,dataframe1,on='Name',how='left')
```

Also tried with below code:

```
dataframe['New']=dataframe['hours']
dataframe_bkp.loc[:,['New']] =  dataframe_bkp[['Stream','Age','New']].apply(lambda x: 0 if (x.Stream in 
['Maths','Commerce'] & (x.Age in [19,21] ) else dataframe_bkp['New'],axis=1 )
```

Comment: The output is unclear, except for Amit, all students match the 2 conditions

Comment: @mozway  edited the output and added another tried code. Hope this is clear . Here Amit and Ankit falls in the condition which is stream to be in Maths & commerce , Age in 19 & 21.

Comment: One more question, should the age be 19 or 21, or between 19 and 21 (what I understood). In one case use `isin`, in the other `between`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['new_column'] = df['hours'].where(  df['Age'].between(19, 21)
                                     & df['Stream'].isin(['Math', 'Commerce']),
                                     0)
```

Alternative:

```
import numpy as np

m1 = df['Age'].between(19, 21)
m2 = df['Stream'].isin(['Math', 'Commerce'])

df['new_column'] = np.where(m1&m2, df['hours'], 0)
```

Output:

```
        Name  Age    Stream  Percentage  hours  new_column
0      Ankit   21      Math          88      1           1
1       Amit   19  Commerce          92      2           2
2  Aishwarya   20   Science          95      3           0
3   Priyanka   18      Math          70      4           0
4      Priya   17      Math          65      5           0
5    Shaurya   21   Science          78      6           0
```

Comment: @technical you're welcome, so this worked as expected?

Comment: yes @mozway , working.